# HTML: How to make page keep on the "href" page, and open a new page for "onclick"

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

I tried to fix hard code(web link in href) in the following line:

```html
    '<a class="top_a" target="_blank" href="http://10.74.55.99:3000/"><img src="images/load.svg"><img src="images/nbsp.png">LoadServer</a>'
```

modified to：

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openLoadserver() {
        window.location.href = load_server; //defined load_server in other file
    }
</script>
```

```
'<a class="top_a" target="_blank" href="#" onclick="openLoadserver()"><img src="images/load.svg"><img src="images/nbsp.png">LoadServer</a>'
```

The result is, after I click "LoadServer", current page will open the load server page, and a new tab page open the  "current page" again.
My expected result is current page is keeping as original, new tab page will open the load server.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="top_a" onclick="openLoadserver()"><img src="images/load.svg"><img src="images/nbsp.png">LoadServer</a>
```

Notice the difference, the `target` attribute :) You don't need `href` either

Comment: But I want to keep the original page on there, and open a new page to load the load server.

Comment: that's why `iframe` element is for

Comment: Thanks!! I found the solution: use "window.open" instead of "window.location.href" and remove "href" element, use the style "cursor:pointer".